# How to add a count to a php script?

Tags: php, numbers

I want to have a way where I can view the amount of times a script of PHP has been used? I want to have a file, that just has a number in it, then I want to be able to view this. So if 6 people send an email through my php script, then each time it is used it will add 1 to a number then save it to a file?

How could I do this?? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a typical use case for a database. If this is not an option and you still want to deal with a text file as a "database", where exactly are you having issues? Reading the file? Incrementing the value?

Comment: In your script, open a file, read the number, add one to it, write the number to the file.

Comment: Yes believe it or not, I don't know PHP I just know a few bits and bobs that don't link, I don't know ANYTHING about opening files and saving data to them?

Answer (score 2):

You could use php's [`file_get_contents();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`file_put_contents();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) functions:

```
$file = 'count.txt';

if(file_exists($file)){
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    file_put_contents($file, ($current + 1));
}else
    file_put_contents($file, 1);
```

Comment: what will give you `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` if there are no file.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Not anymore :)

Answer (score 2):

```
//Define the name of the file
define('FILE_NAME', 'counter.txt');

//Check is there this file
if (file_exists(FILE_NAME)) {
    //If yes, read out the content of it
    $content = file(FILE_NAME);
    //Put the incrased value
    file_put_contents(FILE_NAME, $content[0] + 1);
} else {
    //Create the file with 1 visitor
    file_put_contents(FILE_NAME, 1);
}
```

Comment: I will never understand, why somebody downvote a tested and working solution.